# scala compiling error: Cannot resolve overloaded method 'withTransaction'

Tags: java, scala, jpa, playframework

I'm new to Scala, and I can't figure out how to solve a compiling error for method `withTransaction` :

`Cannot resolve overloaded method 'withTransaction'`

```
object Global {
  
   def goBootstrap(app: Application) {
    Logger.info(" ****   start *****")
     onGet();

    }

  def onGet() {
    import play.db.jpa.JPA
    Logger.info("Cnnection start");
    JPA.withTransaction(JPA.em =>
    {
      val resultsList = JPA.em.createNamedQuery("findCity").setParameter("name", "Boston").getResultList
    }
    );
    
  }

}
```

This code snippet is located in a Global.scala file in Play project (version 2.3.X). JPA came from import play.db.jpa.JPA

How can I solve this compiling error?

Comment: We need more information, I'm not able to find `Global.scala` in [playframework repository](https://github.com/playframework/playframework). What version are you using? What is the type of `JPA` object?

Comment: Sure:  Play version 2.3.X. JPA came from import play.db.jpa.JPA

Comment: Please update the question with the complete `.scala` file.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that there is no method on JPA whose signature matches the parameters you're passing. You are calling `JPA.withTransaction( () => Unit)`.

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/persistence/play-java-jpa/src/main/java/play/db/jpa/JPAApi.java) there are three methods `withTransaction` with `Unit` return types:

```
void withTransaction(Consumer<EntityManager> block);
void withTransaction(String name, Consumer<EntityManager> block);
void withTransaction(String name, boolean readOnly, Consumer<EntityManager> block);
```

I'm going to assume that you're trying to use the first of those methods. Looking at the [docs for Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) it requires a single argument.

In short, you need to provide an input to your block, something like:

```
   JPA.withTransaction(JPA.em => {
      val resultsList = JPA.em.createNamedQuery("findCity").setParameter("name", name).getResultList
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer me. I tried with the documentation suggestions, and with the first method block of code giving the argument, but the error still remains...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't directly instantiate a JPA connection through scala. Also because the play 2.3 framework does not support this feature: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaHome